# How to start reading excel file from second row in Nestjs?

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I have app in which I have excel file reader and I need to start read it in nest js from second row. Who can give me a simple way how to do it ?

Comment: Share us the code you have done so far. So that we can address the question better

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.